# Problems with Linked Excel Charts in Powerpoint

Tags: excel, powerpoint

I've got a couple of annoying issues that keep occurring with linked charts I have between Excel and PowerPoint.

To describe the set up I have, I have an Excel sheet that I open up each day and refresh the data that feeds the charts. When I then go to open the PowerPoint which contains these linked charts (they are copy and pasted directly from Excel), a couple of issues occur:

- The first issue that occurs is that the data in the chart zips to both ends of the axes:[image]

Looking into this into more detail, I see for some reason that the data sources (which are named ranges in Excel), keep defaulting the sheet name to '[0]':

[image]

I'm not sure why this is occurring each time I try to refresh the graph in PowerPoint? The graph in Excel looks fine.

My second problem is related to the first in that there are just general 'refresh' issues between PowerPoint and Excel. Perhaps I have pasted them in incorrectly, or perhaps my refresh method (right click and 'Select Data' on the chart series within PowerPoint) are incorrect?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't actually have a linked Excel chart; you have a PowerPoint chart with its data linked to Excel. It may seem like the same thing, but they're actually different object types. Try creating your chart IN Excel then selecting it, copying, then Paste Special, As Excel Chart Object, Linked into PPT.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg Hi Steve, I did originally create the chart in Excel, then copy and paste it into PowerPoint.

The only issue I had with pasting as an excel chart object was that it was then hard to resize the graph as it seems to effectively paste the chart as an image (although the data would update)

Comment: I've heard of other people having trouble resizing Excel charts paste/linked into PowerPoint.  I don't know what the cause is, and have never run into the problem myself (though admittedly I don't do all that much charting)